# NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate only past a certain index

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I'm attempting to cull my NSMutableArray of elements with filterUsingPredicate.

The tricky part is that I always want to keep at least 10 items in the array, regardless if whether they pass the predicate test. So something like:

```
NSPredicate * cullPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"distanceFromCurrent <= 25 OR index < 10"];

[self.myArray filterUsingPredicate:cullPredicate];
```

The 'OR index < 10' as an indication of what I'd like to do... I realize it won't work.

Is this possible with predicates? Or do I need to pull out another array with elements starting at 10, apply the filter, and then add it back onto the original array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSPredicate has a `-predicateWithBlock:` method that you can use to do this. Something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [[self.myArray copy] autorelease];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {        
    if ([array indexOfObject:evaluatedObject] < 10) return YES;
    return evaluatedObject.distanceFromCurrent <= 25;
}];
[self.myArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: It should be `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` not `-filterWithPredicate:`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII He said it's an NSMutableArray he's trying to filter. `-[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]` is the correct method (I copied his error, though it crossed my mind that it didn't look right). Anyway, fixed via RichardLovejoy suggesting an edit to my answer.

Comment: Yea I edited that in both question and answer I hope it shows up

Answer (score 1):

```
__block int count = 0;
NSObject * object = myArray[0];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(QDItem * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings) {
    if (object.price == evaluatedObject.price) {
        count ++;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];
[myArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%d", count); // output: 1 if return YES
```